# Convergence of variational posterior

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, inference, functional-data-analysis

Let $q_\lambda(z)\in\mathcal Q$ be the [variational posterior approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_Bayesian_methods) of $p(z|y)$.
Note that the optimal $\lambda^*$ is approximated by the following recursive sequence
$$
\lambda^{(k+1)}=\lambda^{(k)}+\eta_k\nabla_\lambda\mathcal L(\lambda^{(k)}),
$$
where $\mathcal L(\lambda)$ is [the ELBO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidence_lower_bound). I am interested in estimating the $L^2$-norm of $||q_{\lambda^{(k)}}(z)-p(z|y)||$. I would like to ask if someone could point me to a reference and give some hints on this ? Thanks for your time !!